# Problema al intentar cargar una pagina externa en mi sitio web

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber cómo puedo correjir el siguiente error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Cuando intento cargar una página por [ejemplo](https://www.mercadospresoyventas.com)  de la siguiente manera

```
var shops = $('.link_shop');
    shops.on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var rute = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(rute);
        $('#container_shops').load(rute);
});
```

¿Cuál podría ser el error?

Comment: Para se tan exacto solo quiero cargar una pagina externa que no esta en  una seccion de una pagina que esta en mi servidor local y al hacer ese intento con Jquery me proporciona ese error

Answer (score 3):

Tienes un problema de seguridad, para solucionarlo, solo tienes que indicar al servidor que quieres dejar pasar cierto tipo de peticiones.

Indicas que tienes una página web (un dominio) en dónde quieres cargar el contenido de otra (otro dominio distinto), entonces lo que hay que hacer es decirle al servidor en dónde está el elemento a cargar, que el dominio destino puede hacerlo. Puedes hacerlo con un fichero .htaccess en el servidor remoto con el siguiente contenido:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example
```

Siendo foo.example el dominio al que quieres dejar cargar el contenido. Puedes poner un * para dejar pasar a todos (incluído tu localhost).

Puedes ver una explicación completa de todas las posibilidades con ejemplos en https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Si no puedes usar un .htaccess o quieres más control, puedes hacerlo en php, un ejemplo sacado de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains publicada por Nikolay Ivanov sería:

```
$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
if ($http_origin == "http://www.domain1.com" || $http_origin == "http://www.domain2.com" || $http_origin == "http://www.domain3.info") {  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");
}
```

Comment: Listo genial, pero si deseo cargar mas de una dirección en ves de http://foo.example coloco * o que debería hacer?

Comment: Lo ideal sería habiliatar solo a los dominios deseados los métodos usados. Normalmente se usa * (comodín) para indicar que el origen de la petición puede ser cualquier dominio, es como decir que el recurso es de libre acceso. Por ejemplo, para hacer una API pública (accesible desde cualquier dominio) en un servidor que acepte todo tipo de peticiones, el * es lo ideal. Aunque esto hay que estudiarlo un poco a fondo porque la seguridad es muy importante y por ahí hay un vector de ataque. Sin conocer detalles del proyecto a fondo no te podría asegurar nada y tampoco soy un experto en eso.

Comment: Listo esta bien, pero aun me sigue sin funcionar colocando este trozo de codigo en mi .htaccess y en la informacion que tiene mi htacces es la siguiente                                                                        RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /error/error.php

Comment: Añade el contenido de tu .htaccess en la pregunta para aclarar esa parte, he añadido en mi respuesta como hacerlo desde php, sin el .htaccess y de paso para varios dominios, con un enlace en dónde está la solución, tanto por .htaccess como por php.

Comment: Lastimosamente no me funciono ni en php ni en .htaccess

Comment: ¿Algún error o mensaje que puedas mostrarnos? ¿en qué no funcionó exactamente? puede que si detallas mejor el problema, aún pueda ayudarte, péga por ejemplo el código de lo que has intentado.

Comment: Este es codigo al inicio del php

Comment: Este es el codigo al incio del php  `$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
if ($http_origin == "https://www.amazon.com") {  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");
}`

Comment: Si no voy errado, el problema es que no me he debido saber explicar bien, pues el dominio amazon no entiendo que hace ahí, debes poner el dominio que hace la petición, es decir la que lanza el load, en tu caso * ya que estás en localhost. Luego cuando migres la web a un dominio tuyo, deberás cambiarlo por tu dominio y se realiza en la parte del servidor, la que tiene el contenido que intentas cargar con load, imagino que alguna web que tendrás en amazon.

Comment: Entonces seria asi?                                                                  $http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
if ($http_origin == "http://localhost:8080/portal/portal_user/") {  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");
}           o seria asi $http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
if ($http_origin == "http://localhost:8080/portal/portal_user/") {  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");
}

Comment: Bueno, la forma más simple de comprobarlo es hacer un var_dump($http_origin) para ver que debes poner exactamente, mejor haz una prueba simple con * a ver si funciona y si es así, entonces haz el var_dump.

Comment: No me reconoce la variable   `$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];` Me arroja el siguiente enunciado dice que la variable esta indefninida <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: HTTP_ORIGIN in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\Views\portal_user.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
NULL

Comment: Tienes que subirlo al servidor y a ver que valor tiene... un phpinfo() también daría el contenido de la variable si te es más sencillo.